# Amenability of $\textrm{w}_0(L^1(G))$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras, amenability

Let $G$ be an infinite compact group and $A=L^1(G)$. It is known that $c_0(A)$ is amenable [[Runde2020](https://books.google.ca/books?id=A1TUDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA80), p.80] while $\ell^{\infty}(A)$ is not [[Daws2009](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0013091507001083)] .

Let $\textrm{w}_0(A)$ denote the subspace of $\ell^{\infty}(A)$ consisting of all weakly null sequences. $\textrm{w}_0(A)$ is a two-sided closed ideal of $\ell^{\infty}(A)$. Indeed, for any $y\in A^* = L^{\infty}(G)$ and a weakly null sequence $(x_n)$ in $L^1(G)$, $\|y\cdot x_n\|_{L^\infty}\to 0$ and $\|x_n\cdot y\|_{L^\infty}\to 0$ where $\cdot$ is the convolution [[CG1984](https://doi.org/10.5802/aif.968)]. Thus, for any $a=(a_n)\in\ell^{\infty}(A)$ and $x=(x_n)\in\textrm{w}_0(A)$, $$\forall y\in L^{\infty}(G)\hspace{8mm}|\langle y,x_n\cdot a_n\rangle|\leq \|y\cdot \tilde{x}_n\|_{L^\infty}\|a_n\|_{L^1} \leq \|y\cdot \tilde{x}_n\|_{L^\infty} \|a\|_{\ell^{\infty}(A)}\to 0 ,$$ so $xa\in\textrm{w}_0(A)$. Similarly, $ax\in\textrm{w}_0(A)$.

> **Question:** Is $\textrm{w}_0(A)$ an amenable Banach algebra?

Clearly, $\textrm{w}_0(A)$ and the quotient $\ell^{\infty}(A)/\textrm{w}_0(A)$ can't both be amenable.

Comment: Have you looked at whether $\textrm{w}_0(L^1(G))$ has a bounded approximate identity? The answer (positive or negative) does not seem obvious to me.

Comment: @YemonChoi I thought it did at the time I posted the question. I strongly suspect it does after thinking over. I realize I do not have an answer to whether $(w_0(A))^2$ is dense in $w_0(A)$ yet.

Comment: My own thinking is that if we take $G={\bf T}$ and define $\chi_n(e^{i\theta})=e^{in\theta}$, then any enumeration of $\{ \chi_n \colon n \in {\bf Z}\}$ ought to be a weakly null sequence in $L^1({\bf T})$, but it seems hard to find an element of $\textrm{w}_0(L^1({\bf T}))$ that "approximately fixes" all of these different weakly null sequences. However I do not yet have a proof that this is impossible.

Comment: @YemonChoi Thanks for an explicit example, this answers my question for $G=\mathbb{T}$. For visitors, $\|\chi - a\chi\| \geq 1$ for $\chi = (\chi_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and all $a\in w_0(L^1(\mathbb{T}))$. So there cannot exist a b.a.i., and so $w_0(L^1(\mathbb{T}))$ is not amenable. This should work similarly for all compact G.